# What is the best suitable naming format of images uploaded by user in web server folder?

Tags: mysql, database

I was write add product advertise code where a user can u upload product images.
But when I plan to store image names, I notice image name formats are random it may be very big or Unreadable sometimes like below example.

```
img_851965_1_1522909196739_22_649825_8_1522909575.jpg
zxb01.png
```

a user and delete the previous images or upload a new one on the same product advertised.
therefore, it may also cause duplicate uploads.
So in keeping such things in mind What is the best practices to upload images in host folder so that it can be easily manageable from both admin & user's side.
please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: Upload image as some random string (timestamp-userid-random string), store this file-name in db with normal name (user inputed) and some description and additional informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to upload images with the timestamp before the file extension, So it will make sure that every file is unique. 
See below code:

```
$file = pathinfo($_FILES["p_image"]["name"]);
$image_path = $file['filename'].'_'.time().'.'.$file['extension'];
```

Comment: In the odd event that two people try to upload the same file name at the same time your code will not work. unlikely but could happen.

Comment: Therefore you can check, if the file exist. And in this case perform and incrementation with the suffix timestamp_X_.file. However, that should only be considered, if it makes sense.

Comment: In that case, we can add additional parameters like user id in the file name.